# indentfirst package missing on MiKTeX

Tags: packages, miktex

I started to make documents using LaTeX, and the packages I normally use includes indentfirst. Last night, I checked for updates, and proceeded with the updates. After the update, the command line returned something like 'indentfirst.sty not found'. I tried to find it on the MiKTeX Console, but it is nowhere to be found. Am I missing something?

Comment: indentfirst is in latex-tools. The package has been renamed, perhaps your miktex isn't in sync. Go to the miktex console and run the task "update package database", both in user and admin mode (and check in both modes for updates and for not installed packages. )

Comment: When is it renamed? Since I don't have a stable Internet connection, I can't update packages often.

Comment: does it matter when? It happens sometimes that packages are rearranged or names cleaned up. In this cases you will have to sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Ulrike Fischer,

> `indentfirst` is in `latex-tools`. The package has been renamed, perhaps your MiKTeX isn't in sync. Go to the MiKTeX Console and run the task "Update package database", both in user and admin mode (and check in both modes for updates and for not installed packages. )